# I keep getting errors trying to genere entities from existing database using Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

When I run this in my console:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml
```

I receive the next error:

> Table concurrentie_ean_autocheck has no primary key. Doctrine does not support reverse engineering from tables that don't have a primary key.

I also tried to use a filter like this, to select one table.

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --filter="bestelling_naw" --force
```

And got the same error.

Comment: Well the message is pretty clear no? Can you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE concurrentie_ean_autocheck` and put the result here? As doctrine says most likely it doesn't have a primary ID

Comment: What does the structure of this table look like?